# Sanitizing string parameters in Cosmos DB to avoid SQL injection

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have an application in which a Cosmos DB SQL Query is constructed dynamically, with some parts coming from untrusted user input. These parts are all string parameters in the `WHERE` clause and always enclosed in single quotes. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE 
    c.prop1 = '{userInput1}' AND 
    STARTSWITH(c['{userInput2}'], '{userInput3}')
```

For various reasons it's not possible to use library features like `SqlParameter` to sanitize the user input, which obviously would be the ideal solution.

But given this constraint, would it be sufficient to escape backslashes  and single quotes in the user input, i.e. replace `\` by `\\` and `'` by `\'` , in order to avoid all SQL injection attacks?

---

(Updated to reflect the comment by @404)

Comment: You can't write or otherwise do anything destructive via query with Cosmos DB. So while you can (and certainly should) check inputs, you should not need to apply the vigor to this that people normally would with a relational database where you can do very destructive things with SQL Injection.

Comment: No it's not enough. You would have to be very familiar with the rules to properly sanitize the query. As example: If I were to use a value like `\' OR 1=1 --` on your example I would escape your escape character and inject my own code. You could also opt to check on allowed characters which would be way easier to check.

Comment: @MarkBrown Disagree; even if you can only query data you'll still be able to get access to data you normally should not or stress the database with 'complicated' queries.

Comment: @404 That's a nice one! I've updated the question accordingly.